# Powershell Sort with Custom Sorting Expression

Tags: sorting, powershell

I have a directory containing numbered directories:

```
Archive
 |-1
 |-2
 |-3
 |-...
```

I need to create the next directory numerically. For which I am currently doing

```
$lastArchive = ls .\Archive | sort Name | select -Last 1
$dirName = '1'
if($lastArchive) {
  $dirName = ([int]$lastArchive.Name)+1
}
```

This of course fails once we get to 10 which by sorting rules follows after 1 not 9. I need the sort expression to actually be `[int]$_.Name` - how would I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need to change that first line as follows:

```
$lastArchive = ls .\Archive | 
               Sort-Object -property @{Expression={[int]$_.Name}} | 
               Select-Object -Last 1
```

Then, you can create the next directory in numerical order like this:

```
mkdir ([int]$lastArchive.Name + 1).ToString()
```